# How to configure Bootstrap 3 Datepicker that the user can not choose the time until he picks a date?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need help with Bootstrap 3 Datepicker (a reference to the manual https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

This is screenshot of my form http://joxi.ru/VrwWzpeiKn4jQr  I use Bootstrap 3 Datepicker for selection date and time in a field “Date”. Selection process, screenshot - joxi.ru/Q2KD1jqu9Dvy5A

Field “Date” has a restriction, user can only choose a date which is later present for 8 days or more. There is a problem during the selection of the date, if  you  choose a time before a date (you first click on the clock, screenshot -joxi.ru/zANp6QBflYj1xm ) Datepicker clears the field “Date” at all.

How to stop clearing field “Date”? And second question, how to configure Datepicker plugin that the user can not choose the time until he picks a date?

Error: screenshot - joxi.ru/YmE13qpfZpMG1m, it happens  when you click the arrow to select the time value the field “Date” is cleared, and time can not be changed. I think this is due to parameter `minDate`, if this param is commented  there is no error!

**Code:**

```
$('#Date').datetimepicker({ 
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:00",   
  minDate:moment().add(2, 'days')
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using last version of the picker? I can't reproduce the issue you described using the code you posted. Maybe you can add a snippet or a fiddle showing the issue instead of using so many screenshots.

Comment: Add link to my test resource http://inviziblll.ru/kmyt-zniis/test-3.html